# Why does update to a dll need recompilation and sometime not?

Tags: c++, dll, compilation

Why does update to a dll need recompilation and sometime not?

Comment: Could you come up with a more detailed example?

Comment: Can you supply an example of when an update does not need recompilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "Binary Compatibility". Keeping this compatibility is not easy, and the information on this are very spare. You should google and test it yourself.

Here are some (incomplete) guide for keeping the compatibility:

- http://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++
- http://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Examples

If you use COM and follow the COM guide, you should be safe all the time.

note: some compiler flags also break binary compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously a change to a DLL will require recompiling that DLL.  However, I think the question you're asking is why you may have to recompile programs that link to that DLL.

There aren't too many ways to change a DLL that will require recompiling code that links with it.  If you change the calling convention, or whether the DLL uses a multithreaded/single threaded runtime, or change the parameters that are passed to various functions, or remove functions altogether then you'll have to recompile (**please note:  this list is NOT exhaustive**).  If you simply fix a bug inside one of the functions that doesn't change how the function is called, then you won't have to recompile code that dynamically links with the DLL.

Comment: you forgot the case when export symbols change, as the program won't even start correctly if the OS cannot find a linked symbol

Comment: I could swear that I wrote (in bold) "please note:  This list is NOT exhaustive."  And I can swear that usually means "there may be cases that I did not put on the list."